# MySQL JDBC driver not found in Tomcat 7 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, tomcat7, ubuntu-14.04

I am deploying an application in a Tomcat 7 on My Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Profile.

I just added the file `mysql-connector-java-5.1.25.ja`r to `/var/lib/tomcat7/common/lib` and `/usr/share/tomcat7/lib`, even that when I start the application I have this error:

```
Dec 19, 2015 9:29:14 AM org.apache.naming.NamingContext lookup
WARNING: Unexpected exception resolving reference
java.sql.SQLException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:254)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:182)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:701)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:635)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:486)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:144)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:116)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:103)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory.createDataSource(DataSourceFactory.java:554)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory.getObjectInstance(DataSourceFactory.java:242)
    at org.apache.naming.factory.ResourceFactory.getObjectInstance(ResourceFactory.java:141)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:321)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:842)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:153)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:830)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:167)
    at fr.telecom.config.PersistenceConfig.dataSource(PersistenceConfig.java:109)
    at fr.telecom.config.PersistenceConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$424c908c.CGLIB$dataSource$2(<generated>)
    at fr.telecom.config.PersistenceConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$424c908c$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$1602d00c.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:318)
    at fr.telecom.config.PersistenceConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$424c908c.dataSource(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331)
    at fr.telecom.config.PersistenceConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$424c908c.dataSource(<generated>)
    at fr.telecom.config.PersistenceConfig.entityManagerFactory(PersistenceConfig.java:158)
    at fr.telecom.config.PersistenceConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$424c908c.CGLIB$entityManagerFactory$1(<generated>)
    at fr.telecom.config.PersistenceConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$424c908c$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$1602d00c.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:318)
    at fr.telecom.config.PersistenceConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$424c908c.entityManagerFactory(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1051)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:828)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4971)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5467)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1073)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:553)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1648)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1445)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.upload(HTMLManagerServlet.java:284)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:206)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:213)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:315)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:246)
    ... 106 more
```

this is the tomcat start script

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# /etc/init.d/tomcat7 -- startup script for the Tomcat 6 servlet engine
#
# Written by Miquel van Smoorenburg <miquels@cistron.nl>.
# Modified for Debian GNU/Linux by Ian Murdock <imurdock@gnu.ai.mit.edu>.
# Modified for Tomcat by Stefan Gybas <sgybas@debian.org>.
# Modified for Tomcat6 by Thierry Carrez <thierry.carrez@ubuntu.com>.
# Modified for Tomcat7 by Ernesto Hernandez-Novich <emhn@itverx.com.ve>.
# Additional improvements by Jason Brittain <jason.brittain@mulesoft.com>.
#
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          tomcat7
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $remote_fs $network
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs $remote_fs $network
# Should-Start:      $named
# Should-Stop:       $named
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start Tomcat.
# Description:       Start the Tomcat servlet engine.
### END INIT INFO

set -e

PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin
NAME=tomcat7
DESC="Tomcat servlet engine"
DEFAULT=/etc/default/$NAME
JVM_TMP=/tmp/tomcat7-$NAME-tmp

if [ `id -u` -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "You need root privileges to run this script"
    exit 1
fi

# Make sure tomcat is started with system locale
if [ -r /etc/default/locale ]; then
    . /etc/default/locale
    export LANG
fi

. /lib/lsb/init-functions

if [ -r /etc/default/rcS ]; then
    . /etc/default/rcS
fi


# The following variables can be overwritten in $DEFAULT

# Run Tomcat 7 as this user ID and group ID
TOMCAT7_USER=tomcat7
TOMCAT7_GROUP=tomcat7

# this is a work-around until there is a suitable runtime replacement 
# for dpkg-architecture for arch:all packages
# this function sets the variable OPENJDKS
find_openjdks()
{
        for jvmdir in /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-*
        do
                if [ -d "${jvmdir}" -a "${jvmdir}" != "/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-common" ]
                then
                        OPENJDKS=$jvmdir
                fi
        done
        for jvmdir in /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-*
        do
                if [ -d "${jvmdir}" -a "${jvmdir}" != "/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-common" ]
                then
                        OPENJDKS="${OPENJDKS} ${jvmdir}"
                fi
        done
}

OPENJDKS=""
find_openjdks
# The first existing directory is used for JAVA_HOME (if JAVA_HOME is not
# defined in $DEFAULT)
JDK_DIRS="/usr/lib/jvm/default-java ${OPENJDKS} /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle"

# Look for the right JVM to use
for jdir in $JDK_DIRS; do
    if [ -r "$jdir/bin/java" -a -z "${JAVA_HOME}" ]; then
    JAVA_HOME="$jdir"
    fi
done
export JAVA_HOME

# Directory where the Tomcat 6 binary distribution resides
CATALINA_HOME=/usr/share/$NAME

# Directory for per-instance configuration files and webapps
CATALINA_BASE=/var/lib/$NAME

# Use the Java security manager? (yes/no)
TOMCAT7_SECURITY=no

# Default Java options
# Set java.awt.headless=true if JAVA_OPTS is not set so the
# Xalan XSL transformer can work without X11 display on JDK 1.4+
# It also looks like the default heap size of 64M is not enough for most cases
# so the maximum heap size is set to 128M
if [ -z "$JAVA_OPTS" ]; then
    JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx128M"
fi

# End of variables that can be overwritten in $DEFAULT

# overwrite settings from default file
if [ -f "$DEFAULT" ]; then
    . "$DEFAULT"
fi

if [ ! -f "$CATALINA_HOME/bin/bootstrap.jar" ]; then
    log_failure_msg "$NAME is not installed"
    exit 1
fi

POLICY_CACHE="$CATALINA_BASE/work/catalina.policy"

if [ -z "$CATALINA_TMPDIR" ]; then
    CATALINA_TMPDIR="$JVM_TMP"
fi

# Set the JSP compiler if set in the tomcat7.default file
if [ -n "$JSP_COMPILER" ]; then
    JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dbuild.compiler=\"$JSP_COMPILER\""
fi

SECURITY=""
if [ "$TOMCAT7_SECURITY" = "yes" ]; then
    SECURITY="-security"
fi

# Define other required variables
CATALINA_PID="/var/run/$NAME.pid"
CATALINA_SH="$CATALINA_HOME/bin/catalina.sh"

# Look for Java Secure Sockets Extension (JSSE) JARs
if [ -z "${JSSE_HOME}" -a -r "${JAVA_HOME}/jre/lib/jsse.jar" ]; then
    JSSE_HOME="${JAVA_HOME}/jre/"
fi

catalina_sh() {
    # Escape any double quotes in the value of JAVA_OPTS
    JAVA_OPTS="$(echo $JAVA_OPTS | sed 's/\"/\\\"/g')"

    AUTHBIND_COMMAND=""
    if [ "$AUTHBIND" = "yes" -a "$1" = "start" ]; then
        AUTHBIND_COMMAND="/usr/bin/authbind --deep /bin/bash -c "
    fi

    # Define the command to run Tomcat's catalina.sh as a daemon
    # set -a tells sh to export assigned variables to spawned shells.
    TOMCAT_SH="set -a; JAVA_HOME=\"$JAVA_HOME\"; source \"$DEFAULT\"; \
        CATALINA_HOME=\"$CATALINA_HOME\"; \
        CATALINA_BASE=\"$CATALINA_BASE\"; \
        JAVA_OPTS=\"$JAVA_OPTS\"; \
        CATALINA_PID=\"$CATALINA_PID\"; \
        CATALINA_TMPDIR=\"$CATALINA_TMPDIR\"; \
        LANG=\"$LANG\"; JSSE_HOME=\"$JSSE_HOME\"; \
        cd \"$CATALINA_BASE\"; \
        \"$CATALINA_SH\" $@"

    if [ "$AUTHBIND" = "yes" -a "$1" = "start" ]; then
        TOMCAT_SH="'$TOMCAT_SH'"
    fi

    # Run the catalina.sh script as a daemon
    set +e
    touch "$CATALINA_PID" "$CATALINA_BASE"/logs/catalina.out
    chown $TOMCAT7_USER "$CATALINA_PID" "$CATALINA_BASE"/logs/catalina.out
    start-stop-daemon --start -b -u "$TOMCAT7_USER" -g "$TOMCAT7_GROUP" \
        -c "$TOMCAT7_USER" -d "$CATALINA_TMPDIR" -p "$CATALINA_PID" \
        -x /bin/bash -- -c "$AUTHBIND_COMMAND $TOMCAT_SH"
    status="$?"
    set +a -e
    return $status
}

case "$1" in
  start)
    if [ -z "$JAVA_HOME" ]; then
        log_failure_msg "no JDK or JRE found - please set JAVA_HOME"
        exit 1
    fi

    if [ ! -d "$CATALINA_BASE/conf" ]; then
        log_failure_msg "invalid CATALINA_BASE: $CATALINA_BASE"
        exit 1
    fi

    log_daemon_msg "Starting $DESC" "$NAME"
    if start-stop-daemon --test --start --pidfile "$CATALINA_PID" \
        --user $TOMCAT7_USER --exec "$JAVA_HOME/bin/java" \
        >/dev/null; then

        # Regenerate POLICY_CACHE file
        umask 022
        echo "// AUTO-GENERATED FILE from /etc/tomcat7/policy.d/" \
            > "$POLICY_CACHE"
        echo ""  >> "$POLICY_CACHE"
        cat $CATALINA_BASE/conf/policy.d/*.policy \
            >> "$POLICY_CACHE"

        # Remove / recreate JVM_TMP directory
        rm -rf "$JVM_TMP"
        mkdir -p "$JVM_TMP" || {
            log_failure_msg "could not create JVM temporary directory"
            exit 1
        }
        chown $TOMCAT7_USER "$JVM_TMP"

        catalina_sh start $SECURITY
        sleep 5
            if start-stop-daemon --test --start --pidfile "$CATALINA_PID" \
            --user $TOMCAT7_USER --exec "$JAVA_HOME/bin/java" \
            >/dev/null; then
            if [ -f "$CATALINA_PID" ]; then
                rm -f "$CATALINA_PID"
            fi
            log_end_msg 1
        else
            log_end_msg 0
        fi
    else
            log_progress_msg "(already running)"
        log_end_msg 0
    fi
    ;;
  stop)
    log_daemon_msg "Stopping $DESC" "$NAME"

    set +e
    if [ -f "$CATALINA_PID" ]; then 
        start-stop-daemon --stop --pidfile "$CATALINA_PID" \
            --user "$TOMCAT7_USER" \
            --retry=TERM/20/KILL/5 >/dev/null
        if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
            log_progress_msg "$DESC is not running but pid file exists, cleaning up"
        elif [ $? -eq 3 ]; then
            PID="`cat $CATALINA_PID`"
            log_failure_msg "Failed to stop $NAME (pid $PID)"
            exit 1
        fi
        rm -f "$CATALINA_PID"
        rm -rf "$JVM_TMP"
    else
        log_progress_msg "(not running)"
    fi
    log_end_msg 0
    set -e
    ;;
   status)
    set +e
    start-stop-daemon --test --start --pidfile "$CATALINA_PID" \
        --user $TOMCAT7_USER --exec "$JAVA_HOME/bin/java" \
        >/dev/null 2>&1
    if [ "$?" = "0" ]; then

        if [ -f "$CATALINA_PID" ]; then
            log_success_msg "$DESC is not running, but pid file exists."
            exit 1
        else
            log_success_msg "$DESC is not running."
            exit 3
        fi
    else
        log_success_msg "$DESC is running with pid `cat $CATALINA_PID`"
    fi
    set -e
        ;;
  restart|force-reload)
    if [ -f "$CATALINA_PID" ]; then
        $0 stop
        sleep 1
    fi
    $0 start
    ;;
  try-restart)
        if start-stop-daemon --test --start --pidfile "$CATALINA_PID" \
        --user $TOMCAT7_USER --exec "$JAVA_HOME/bin/java" \
        >/dev/null; then
        $0 start
    fi
        ;;
  *)
    log_success_msg "Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart|try-restart|force-reload|status}"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac

exit 0
```

Comment: Have you tried to put this jar inside $CATALINA_HOME/lib ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library was well placed. 
It was a lack of permissions:

```
chmod 777 mysql-connector-java-5.1.25.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

Very likely /var/lib/tomcat7/common/lib is not on the classpath. Check your Tomcat startup script. Have you try adding it to /var/lib/tomcat7/ assuming this is the location that tomcat load its base lib.